# I was using gparted on ubuntu for usb-stick and mistakenly deleted 1 TB Ubuntu hard drive, all data

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

[image]I was using gparted tryong format usb-stick and mistakenly deleted 1 TB hard drive. I don't know what happened. When I try to see my hard drive in nautilus, there is HD named "Recycle bin" and its empty. Is there any change to recover my files/filesystem back? Here is picture from HD in gparted. I'm newbie, so I hope that your answer is step by step to get my files back.

Jari

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Or see The Sleuth Kit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sleuth_Kit

Comment: Thanks Karel. I have looked at many testdisk videos how to use them. But they are so complicated and there is an even greater possibility to get a lot more bad things and  destroy my hard drive. Because I can't be shure what really happens next when I use it. Thanks waltinator, I have never heard it before (The Sleuth Kit), Is it possible that in my case I have formatted my hard drive like usb-stick for fat32? My other two linux hard drives are ext4?!

Comment: Anybody there who can help with this issue? The difference in this not how to get data back? The issue is much deeper, when the filesystem of hard drive is formatted and there is wrong filesystem and the data is somewhere there behind wrong file system,  perhaps? What is the best way to start thinking how to get data back?